# PostgreSQL Data Connection/Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: database, visual-studio-2008, postgresql

I'm trying to find a way to browse a PostgreSQL database from the Visual Studio 2008 "Server Explorer" panel. I downloaded Npgsql but as I understand that's only a library for the code itself, not the Server Explorer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Npgsql is a .NET provider for PostgreSQL. Whether or not a given provider integrates with Server Explorer depends on whether it supports [DDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379576.aspx), which Npgsl as of now does not, but [this support is planned for future versions](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/roadmap.html).

However, if all you want to do is to be able to browse a PostgreSQL database in Server Explorer, you can do this by installing the [psqlODBC](http://psqlodbc.projects.postgresql.org/), the PostgreSQL ODBC driver, and connecting via the [.NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=6ccd8427-1017-4f33-a062-d165078e32b1&displaylang=en).

[alt text http://www.codingthewheel.com/image.axd?picture=postgre_sql_server_explorer.png](http://www.codingthewheel.com/image.axd?picture=postgre_sql_server_explorer.png)

Also, I should mention that Npgsql DOES have some [design-time integration with Visual Studio](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html) - for example you can use NpgsqlConnection objects from the toolbar and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

I looked for this earlier this year and found someone that on some mailing list wrote that they were working on that for Npgsql but it not yet available.

We actually discarded Npsql and now uses [dotConnect for PostgreSQL](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/) instead. It is a commercial product with a free option but you have to pay to the get the Visual Studio integration.